# Jquery skip unwanted attribute with sort

Tags: jquery

I have two attribute `data-num` and `data-first` , `data-first` have `0` or `1`, I want to skip those element for sorting if `data-first` is `1`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" data-num="99" data-first="0"></div>
  <div class="item" data-num="55" data-first="1"></div>
  <div class="item" data-num="22" data-first="0"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var $wrapper = $('.container');
    $wrapper.find('.item').sort(function (a, b) {
     if(a.dataset.first == 1){
        a.remove();
     }
       return +b.dataset.num - +a.dataset.num;
    })
    .appendTo($wrapper);
</script>
```

Comment: Show HTML aswell please

Comment: for this you can use jQuery.uniqueSort().

Comment: @RichardMauritz added html code

Comment: @ManishPatolia uniqueSort for array right ?

Comment: yes for array...

Comment: @ManishPatolia how it can use in my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

In this case, this will work.

```
$wrapper.find('.item[data-first=0]')
```

But so would this

```
$wrapper.find('.item[data-first!=1]')
```

The difference would matter if you ever had a `data-first=2` value. If its only 0 or 1, then it doesn't matter which version you use.

So your final script would look like this:

```
var $wrapper = $('.container');
$wrapper.find('.item[data-first!=1]').sort(function (a, b) {
  return +b.dataset.num - +a.dataset.num;
})
.appendTo($wrapper);
```